# AsEnumerable в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server

Здравствуйте уважаемые специалисты! Хочу задать вопрос по Entity Framework. Например у меня есть такой код

```
return from city in context.City
       where SomeFunc(city, id, name)
       select new City(city);

bool SomeFunc(City city, int id, int name)
{
    return city.Id == id || city.Name == name || city.Code == name;       
}
```

когда я выполняю код то получаю такое исключение

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method  and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

В интернете советуют использовать метод AsEnumerable

```
return from city in context.City.AsEnumerable()
       where SomeFunc(city, id, name)
       select new City(city);
```

Это работает но очень медленно потому что context.City.AsEnumerable() выдает мне сразу все города из таблицы и потом выполняет к ним функцию SomeFunc

Можно написать так:

```
return from city in context.City
       where city.Id == id || city.Name == name || city.Code == name
       select new City(city);
```

и все будет работать быстро. Но тогда получится такая проблема - это условие может быть использовано еще в каком-то методе и тогда надо будет дублировать этот код что не есть хорошо. Как быть? Может быть в Entity Framework есть какой то способ избежать и дублирования кода и выполнения условий в SQL а не в C#? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Попробуйте перейти от Func к Expression:

```
Expression<Func<City, bool>> SomeFunc(int id, string name)
{
    return city => city.Id == id || city.Name == name || city.Code == name;
}

var result = cities.Where(SomeFunc(id, name)).Select(city => new City(city));
```

Comment: спасибо большое! а можете объяснить как и почему это работает? почему при использовании обычного Func все было медленно, а с Expression стало быстро?

Comment: @JuniorTwo: Дело в том, что LINQ умеет разобрать Expression на составные части и превратить его в SQL, так что `SomeFunc` на самом деле вычисляется на стороне базы данных! Без `Expression` получается обыкновенная функция, а заглянуть внутрь _функции_ и превратить её в SQL LINQ не умеет.

Магия состоит в том, что лямбда-выражение

    city => city.Id == id || city.Name == name || city.Code == name

может трактоваться компилятором и как обыкновенное арифметическое выражение, и как Expression, в зависимости от контекста.

Comment: @VladD спасибо!

Comment: @JuniorTwo: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5):

Если условие используется в нескольких местах, вынесите эту фильтрацию в отдельный метод:

```
private IQueryable<City> GetFilteredCities(int id, string name)
{
    return context.City
        .Where(city => city.Id == id || city.Name == name || city.Code == name);
}
```

Затем, его можно использовать в других методах:

```
var cities1 = GetFilteredCities(1, "Moscow");
var cities2 = GetFilteredCities(3, "London").Where( ... ).Select( ... );
```

В результате выполнения метода `GetFilteredCities` SQL-запрос выполняться не будет, а будет просто формироваться условие. Непосредественно запрос выполнится при вызове методов `AsEnumerable()`, `ToList()` или `ToArray()`.